# Speeding up datagridview cell font change

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I've testes a lot and the problem is 100% one of these code's (which I can see clearly in debug mode):

```
datagridview1.Rows[rowOld].Cells[cell].Style.Font = datagridview1.DefaultCellStyle.Font;
```

and it doen't matter if I try to change the font with other codes like:

```
Font fontBold = null;
fontBold = new Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 11.5F, FontStyle.Bold);
datagridview1.Rows[r].Cells[c].Style.Font = fontBold;
```

or:

```
datagridview1.Rows[r].Cells[c].Style.Font = new Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 8.25F, FontStyle.Regular);
```

Everyone of them need about 800-1000 ms.
That's weird? Or just normal?

My "datagridview1" contains just about 4000 cows and 7 cells.
Everything is fast, as it should be, but if I change the font it takes amazing time FOR JUST 1 !!! cell font change.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this. Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: You are right, thank you. I've found the "slow-maker" hehe

Comment: [Best Practices for Scaling the Windows Forms DataGridView Control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/best-practices-for-scaling-the-windows-forms-datagridview-control)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was I had **AutoSizeColumnsMod = AllCells** in the **dataGridView1 properties**.

Which I need, but it calls it at every change.
So I use it just once programmatically in the code and not as before in the **dataGridView1 properties**.

Still thanks for every assistant.

Answer (score 2):

What I don't like in your code is that you use 'new Font()' for every single cell. I believe your cells can share same fonts objects. I'm not sure if this will solve your problem, but try to make predefined Font class variables. For example create some Font class instances as member variables of your WinForms class, then just refer to existing Font variables. In Windows GDI each font holds handle (HFONT) which must be disposed after you have finished working with it. You loose some performance here.

For example:

```
private Font _fontArial = new Font("Arial", 8.25F, FontStyle.Regular);
private Font _fontArialBold = new Font("Arial", 8.25F, FontStyle.Bold);
private Font _fontTahoma = new Font("Tahoma", 8.25F, FontStyle.Regular);
```

then just reuse predefined fonts:

```
datagridview1.Rows[r].Cells[c].Style.Font = _fontArialBold;
```

And also to note, you can make predefined Styles, and replace entire styles of DataGridView cells, not just fonts.

Comment: No I had Font fontBold = null;
fontBold = new Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 11.5F, FontStyle.Bold); just called one time, in Form_Load.
But still thank you :)